# Orthogonal diagonalize this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

how would one orthogonally diagonalize the matrix $A$ = $\begin{pmatrix}a&0&b\\ 0&a&0\\ b&0&a\end{pmatrix}$

where $b≠0$?

Comment: OK. I’ve done that. Now what?

Comment: Why is this on hold?  It is an interesting question that is on-topic.  Seems to me the poster merely needs a push in the right direction.

Comment: @ulaff.net Quite likely because it doesn’t even come close to meeting the [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) guidelines. It’s not even a question. It’s an imperative that looks an awful lot like it was pasted directly from a problem set.

Comment: @amd is this better?

Comment: Not much, but then I’m not one of the people who voted to put your question on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem.  Read up on "Jacobi rotations"

Here is the short answer:

Focus on the matrix $ \left( \begin{array}{c c}
a & b\\
b & a 
\end{array}
\right)
$.
A Jacobi rotation is given by
$$ \left( \begin{array}{c c}
c & s\\
-s & c 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $ c = \cos( \theta ) $ and $ s = \sin( \theta ) $ 
such that, for this problem,
$$ \left( \begin{array}{c c}
c & s\\
-s & c 
\end{array}
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{c c}
a & b\\
b & a 
\end{array}
\right)
 \left( \begin{array}{c c}
c & s\\
-s & c 
\end{array}
\right)^T
$$
is diagonal.
You then take that, and use it as follows:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{c c}
c & 0 & s\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-s & 0 & c 
\end{array}
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{c c c }
a & 0 & b\\
0 & a & 0 \\
b & 0 & a 
\end{array}
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{c c}
c & 0 & s\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-s & 0 & c 
\end{array}
\right)^T
$$
The exact formula for $ c $ and $ s $ I don't quite remember.

A rotation is an orthogonal matrix, so it what you need.

Comment: Historic note: Jacobi's method was the first iterative method discovered for computing eigenvalues, about 175 years ago. It was used to compute the periods of the planets.  There is a footnote in the paper that attributes the hand calculations to Jacobi's student Seidel.  If I recall correctly.  It has been 25 years since I read the paper.

Comment: It’s pretty obvious from inspection that $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are eigenvectors of the smaller matrix.

Comment: Yes!  That is the final hint that makes it all come together.  (I originally posted a comment that gave it all away, but let's see if the poster can finish it off now.)